# Testing the fit of polychoric correlation

Tags: goodness-of-fit, item-response-theory, polychoric

I’m using polychoric correlations for my work. According to Kampen and Weeren (2017):

> In order to prevent this questionable research practice, it is recommended that in applications of the polychoric correlation coefficient, data is tested with goodness-of-fit of the BND, that such statistic is reported in published applications, and that the polychoric correlation is not applied when the test is significant.

What I’m not sure is how to perform the said test in R. I tried looking through popular packages on the topics, such as `psych`, `mirt` or `polycor`, but neither of them seems to have an option to check the empirical fit of polychoric correlation coefficients on the data.

Does anyone know of any way of testing goodness of fit for polychoric correlation? Sadly, my mathematical skill is not enough to compute the test in the referenced paper “by hand”.

Kampen, J. K., & Weeren, A. (2017). A recommendation for applied researchers to substantiate the claim that ordinal variables are the product of underlying bivariate normal distributions. Quality & quantity, 51(5), 2163–2170. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11135-016-0378-2

Comment: The IRT approach doesn't use the polychoric matrix at all, nor does it strictly make the assumption above underlying bi-variate normality between contingency tables, which is why you don't see tests for this in `mirt`.

Comment: @philchalmers Thank you for clearing up the confusion about IRT. One more question, if I may: looking at ```mirt::mirt```, all ```dentype``` not assuming normality are only available to unidimensional models. Could you point me towards resources on how to either relax or check the normality assumption for multidimensional models? Thank you.

Comment: This appears in many areas, but see Carol Woods' work on estimating the latent trait distribution by way of splines. That should be a good start into the topic.

Comment: As for multidimensional models this area is quite limited, largely due to the computational complexity required to implement such models (they are possible, of course, just complicated with many limiting issues).